# Program with mmap(MAP_FIXED) crashes on Linux 2.6.18 && glibc 2.5

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, mmap

Following Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void generate_test_file(int count)
{
    FILE *f;
    int i;

    f = fopen("testfile", "w+");
    for (i=0;i<count;i++) {
            fwrite(&i, 1, sizeof(i), f);
    }
    fclose(f);

}

void test_mmap_directly()
{
    int fd;
    void *area_short, *area_long;

    generate_test_file(1024);
    fd = open("testfile", O_RDONLY);
    assert(fd>=0);

    area_short = mmap(0, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    assert(area_short != MAP_FAILED);

    generate_test_file(1024*1024);
    area_long = mmap(area_short, 4096*1024, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_FIXED, fd, 0);
    assert(area_long != MAP_FAILED);
    assert(area_short == area_long);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    test_mmap_directly();
/* Crashes on shutdown for libc 2.5 and kernel 2.6.18 (CentOS 5) */
}
```

Crashes on shutdown with a Segfault on my CentOS 5 box. Is this a known bug,
should one in general not use MAP_FIXED or is there something wrong with the
Program. Does it also crash on other platforms?

Thanks for any help,

- Johannes

Comment: Does closing `fd` after the first `mmap()` and re-opening it again after the second `generate_test_file()` make a difference? What kind of file system is "testfile" living on? I'm wondering if the truncation/overwriting of the file is causing the file descriptor that's kept open to be inconsistent, which would then cause issues with the second `mmap()`. Also, since `MAP_FIXED` causes overlapping mapped regions to be discarded, maybe the second map kills a mapped shared library or data segment or something.

Comment: It seems as exactly that is happening: the second mmap call kills a shared library. Closing and reopening the file doesn't make a difference.

Comment: *4096*1024* you map 4M over previously reserved 4K via MAP_FIXED. Since you are not controlling the address space, it can override anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you forgotten to use `munmap` on the pointers and `close` on the file descriptor. 
If you have not then the problem is most likely `MAP_FIXED`

I tested on my debian (kernel 2.6.32) and it caused SEGFAULT when using MAP_FIXED flag and worked without the flag (except that the asserts after the second mmap failed which is I think is not unexpected).

accoring to [`man mmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mmap) support for `MAP_FIXED`  is implementation defined and its support is discouraged. I've never used it myself so I cannot think of any solution other than omitting it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Probably MAP_FIXED shouldn't be used but I needed it for a special case in my mmap_allocator (available on github: https://github.com/johannesthoma/mmap_allocator). I already found a workaround. Does the problem persist in recent kernels (say 3.6)?